# Dynamic websites using php without inclusion

Tags: php, include, restful-url

I am developing a website where all 5 main pages(home, about me, contact, blog, my foundation)  are structured different from each other so I dont want to use the include() function to inherit anything from the index. how do I go about going to these pages about me (home, about me, contact, blog, my foundation)

Comment: please, show us your effort you performed to solve the problem upto now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a link from each page to every page. It would be best to create a header.php file which you would include on every page. This file would contain your 'navigation' or the links to all the other pages.  Since you say you don't want to use includes you will have to add this same code at the top of all the pages.  If you want to change them you will have to change them on every page. If you used the include() function instead you would only have to change it once.